# PHP Error logging

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

I have a CenOS server and i want to enable PHP error logging to a file.
I have edited the php.ini file and set

```
error_log = /var/log/httpd/phperror.log
```

and also

```
log_errors = On
```

I've restarted the apache server with `service httpd restart` but still the /var/log/httpd/phperror.log does not get created and no errors are logged. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you check the permissions of this file path? Is it writeable by httpd process?

Comment: I even put /tmp/phperror.log and the file still did not get created.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating an empty file in dir /var/log/httpd/

```
#touch /var/log/httpd/phperror.log
```

After creating the empty file, restart the apache server and check it the log file updated with the error log.

Comment: ...and add write permissions for apache user: `chown apache. /var/log/httpd/phperror.log` and `chmod 750 /var/log/httpd/phperror.log`

Comment: I even put /tmp/phperror.log and the file still did not get created.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better/easier idea to send the php errors to syslog. You won't have to worry about permission problems and the file should already be rotated.

error_log = syslog

Depending on your OS the errors should then go to 
/var/log/messages 
or 
/var/log/syslog